# Get Call Depth Inside React Component

Tags: reactjs, depth, scenegraph

I'm trying to make a scene graph in React that supports nesting components. Something along the lines of:

```
<SceneNode>
  <SceneNode>
    <Thing/>
  </SceneNode>
  <SceneNode>
    <Thing/>
  </SceneNode>
</SceneNode>
```

When a `SceneNode` is mounted I need a way for it to know at what "depth" it is. Is there a way within a component to access that information? e.g.:

```
function SceneNode({children}:{children:ReactNode}) {
  const depth = useCallDepth(); // <- some magic function that lets me know the level of nesting for this node
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

***NOTE***: I've tried the following:

- **Context**: Can't get it to work without having each node create its own context but since context is referenced statically in React I can't access the dynamically created parent contexts from children.
- **Refs**: The nesting of components should be reflected in the DOM elements they produce, but I can't figure out how to determine what the associated component is for a given DOM element - i.e. is this div a `SceneNode` or just a random div? (I suppose I could encode it in an attribute or id, but I was hoping for something a little cleaner and less invasive)
- **Manual**: I can manually specify which nodes are parents (e.g. `<SceneNode parent={true}/>` but that's pretty error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use context for this: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-call-depth-inside-react-component-demo-grvsi?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: You're right!! I misremembered how context works. `useContext` finds the nearest "instance" of a context rather than a static one. Thanks for reminding me.